# Extra space on the right hand side of my web page

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I've finished creating my website, but there are a couple of problems that I cannot seem to figure out.

The main one is that for some reason, there is empty space on the right-hand side. I'm trying to achieve a 'fluid' layout. I've set the widths to 100%. I can't figure out what is going on.

I was wondering if someone could help me with this.

Also, I have a big monitor, so there's whitespace at the bottom. If someone could help me with that, it would be a bonus.

Thanks.

HTML

```
    <body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <a href="http://www.courdec.co.uk"><img src="images/courdec-logo.png"></a>
        <div class="telephone">
            <img src="images/telephone-number.png" />
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div>
            <h2><a href="index.php">Home</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2><a href="services.php">Services</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></h2>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <main>
        <h1>Services</h1>
        <img id="services-image" src="images/image5501.jpg" />
        <div class="service-content">
            <p>Courdec provides a range of commercial and residential painting and decorating services.</p>
            <p>Projects ranging from large commercial premises to New Build.</p>
            <table id="service-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Resin Floors</th>
                    <th>Intumescent Coatings</th>
                    <th>Hygiene Coatings</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Retail, industrial and commercial projects</td>
                    <td>Protecting Wood and Steel from fire</td>
                    <td>Hospitals, Schools and food preparation areas</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Spray Application</th>
                    <th>Wall coverings</th>
                    <th>Floor Markings</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Covering large areas with a wide range of coatings</td>
                    <td>Vinyls, fabrics, silks and hand-printed papers</td>
                    <td>Directional systems, bays and walkways in car parks</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p>Our teams of professional painters and decorators work on all kinds of projects for a wide variety of commercial and private clients.</p>
            <p>Efficient, organised and reliable, we meet all the Health & Safety requirements. We also like to protect the environment, using eco friendly paints.</p>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div>&copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?> Courdec UK Ltd.</div>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans:600|Overpass|Poppins:700|Titillium+Web|Varela+Round|Work+Sans|Titillium+Web:700');

body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(254, 254, 254);
}

.container {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.telephone {
    /*width: 100%;*/
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.telephone > h3 {
    font-family: 'Overpass', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(3, 3, 247);
    text-align: center;
}

nav > div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0px 65px;
}

nav > div:hover {
    background-color: rgb(77, 117, 222);
}

nav > div > h2 {
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
}

h2 > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(225, 230, 243);
}

main {
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Work Sans ExtraBold", sans-serif;
    font-size: 4em;
}

p {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#slides {
    display: none;
}

.home-content {
    padding: 0 2.5em 1em 2.5em;
    text-align: justify;
}

.service-content {
    text-align: center;
}

.service-content > #service-table {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}

#service-table th {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}

#service-table td {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.building-types {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(251, 217, 29);
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    color: rgb(59, 77, 90);
}

.building-types > div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 19%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.has-gallery main {
    height: 1000px;
}

/* List of Albums */

#album-2 {
    display: none;
}

/* -------------- */

#gallery-thumbnails {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
}

#gallery-thumbnails td {
    width: 33%;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#gallery-thumbnails img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 185px;
}

.contact-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

#contact-form {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: left;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="email"]{
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

textarea {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 12em;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    resize: none;
}

input[type="button"] {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #3366FF;
    background-color:#B3C6FF;
    font-family: "Work Sans ExtraBold", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

label {
    font-family: "Titillium Web", sans-serif;
}

.certification {
    padding-top: 2em;
}

#chas {
    width: 125px;
    height: 100px;
}

#dulux {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}

#services-image {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
    border-top: solid 10px rgb(209, 212, 218);
    color: rgb(248, 248, 253);
}

footer > div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24pt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Space on the right is caused by this

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 15px;
    /* padding-left: 15px; */
}
```

Just remove `padding-left` and it will be fine.

If you want to place the footer in bottom either use flexbox or absolute positioning. Here is a good explanation of flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

In the future, you can open your webpage, ctrl+shift+i, then go down the document tree to the problematic element. Hover over it, and it will show where that element is and whether or not it is responsible for the whitespace. Once you ahev found the responsible element, then go to the concentric squares (middle right) and find if it is the margin or border or padding of the element that needs to be decreased.

[image: inspecting element]